# Collision detection and reaction java

Tags: java, arrays, object, collision

I am writing a small game where 20 balloons are created on screen and mouse released on them expands them. They are supposed to 'pop' when one balloon touches another, but at present when I click a balloon it pops a random one and throws an 'Array index out of bounds' exception. I've racked my brain to figure out why my code isn't working but just can't get it. Here's some of the code causing the problem:

```
import comp102.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class BalloonGame implements UIButtonListener, UIMouseListener{
// Fields
private final int numBalloons = 20;
private int currentScore;   // the score for the current game
private int highScore = 0;  // highest score in all games so far.
private int totalPopped = 0;
Balloon balloons[] = new Balloon[numBalloons];

// Constructor 
/** Set up the GUI, start a new game.
 */
public BalloonGame(){
    UI.setMouseListener(this);
    UI.addButton("New Game", this);
    UI.addButton("Lock Score", this);
    this.newGame();
}

// GUI Methods to respond to buttons and mouse
/** Respond to button presses, to start a new game and to end the current game  */
public void buttonPerformed(String cmd){
    if (cmd.equals("New Game")) { this.newGame(); }
    else if (cmd.equals("Lock Score")) { this.endGame(); }
}

/** Respond to mouse released with the main action of the game*/
public void mousePerformed(String action, double x, double y) {
    if (action.equals("released")) {
        this.doAction(x, y);
    }
}

/** Start the game:
Clear the graphics pane
Initialise the score information 
Make a new set of Balloons at random positions
 */
public void newGame(){
    UI.clearGraphics();
    this.currentScore = 0;
    this.totalPopped = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.balloons.length; i++) {
        this.balloons[i] = new Balloon(50 + Math.random()*400, 50 + Math.random()*400);
        this.balloons[i].draw();
    }
    UI.printMessage("New game: click on a balloon.  High score = "+this.highScore);
}

/** Main game action.
Find the balloon at (x,y) if any,
Expand it 
Check whether it is touching another balloon,
If so, update totalPopped, pop both balloons, and remove them from the list
Recalculate the score.
If there are no balloons left, end the game.
 */
public void doAction(double x, double y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.balloons.length; i++) {
        if (this.balloons[i].on(x, y) && !this.balloons[i].isPopped()) {
            this.balloons[i].expand();
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <this.balloons.length; j++) {
            if (this.balloons[i].isTouching(this.balloons[j]) && this.balloons[j] != null)
            {
                this.totalPopped +=2;
                this.balloons[i].pop();
                this.balloons[j].pop();
                this.balloons[i] = null;
                this.balloons[j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    this.calculateScore();
    if (totalPopped == numBalloons) {
        this.endGame();
    }
}

/** Find a balloon that the point (x, y) is on.
 *  Returns null if point is not on any balloon*/
public Balloon findBalloon(double x, double y){
    return null;
}

/** Find and return another balloon that is touching this balloon
 * Returns null if no such Balloon. */
public Balloon findTouching(Balloon balloon){
    return null;
}

/** Calculate the score: sum of the sizes of current ballons, minus
the total of the popped balloons (totalPopped).
Report the score as a message */
public void calculateScore(){
    for (Balloon b: balloons) {
        this.currentScore += b.size();
    }
    if (currentScore >= highScore) {
        this.highScore = this.currentScore;
    }
    UI.printMessage("Score = "+this.currentScore+"    High score = "+this.highScore);
}

/** Returns true if all the balloons have been popped,
 *  Returns false if any of the balloons is not popped */
public boolean allPopped(){
    for (Balloon b : this.balloons){
        if (!b.isPopped()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/** End the current game.
Record the the score as the new high score if it is better 
Print a message
Clear the list of balloons (so the player can't keep playing)
 */
public void endGame(){
    this.highScore = this.currentScore;
    UI.println("High score = " + this.highScore);
    Arrays.fill(balloons, null);
}

// Main
public static void main(String[] arguments){
    BalloonGame ob = new BalloonGame();
}   

}
```

uses the balloon class also:

```
import comp102.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;


/** Represents a balloon that can grow until it pops.
A Balloon can say whether a particular point is on it, and
whether it is touching another balloon.
It can also return its size.
Once it has popped, no point is on it, and it can't touch another balloon.
Also, its size is reported as a negative value.

*/
public class Balloon{
// Fields
private double radius = 10;
private double centerX, centerY;
private Color color;
private boolean popped = false;


// Constructors
/** Construct a new Balloon object. 
    Parameters are the coordinates of the center of the balloon
    Does NOT draw the balloon yet.
*/
public Balloon(double x, double y){
    this.centerX = x;
    this.centerY = y;
    this.color = Color.getHSBColor((float)Math.random(), 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

public void draw(){
    UI.setColor(color);
    UI.fillOval(centerX-radius, centerY-radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    if (!this.popped){
        UI.setColor(Color.black);
        UI.drawOval(centerX-radius, centerY-radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    }
}

/** Make the balloon larger by a random amount between 4 and 10*/
public void expand(){
    if (! this.popped){
        this.radius = this.radius + (Math.random()*6 + 4);
        this.draw();
    }
}

/** pop the balloon (changes colour to gray, draws, and pauses briefly)*/
public void pop(){
    this.color = Color.lightGray;
    this.popped = true;
    this.draw();
    UI.sleep(20);
}

/** Returns true if the balloon has been popped */
public boolean isPopped(){
    return this.popped;
}

/** Returns true if the point (x,y) is on the balloon, and false otherwise */
public boolean on(double x, double y){
    if (popped) return false;
    double dx = this.centerX - x;
    double dy = this.centerY - y;
    return ((dx*dx + dy*dy) < (this.radius * this.radius));
}

/** Returns true if this Balloon is touching the other balloon, and false otherwise
 *  Returns false if either balloon is popped. */
public boolean isTouching(Balloon other){
    if (this.popped || other.popped) return false;
    double dx = other.centerX - this.centerX;
    double dy = other.centerY - this.centerY;
    double dist = other.radius + this.radius;
    return (Math.hypot(dx,dy) < dist);
}

/** Calculates and returns the area of the balloon
 *  Returns it in "centi-pixels" (ie, number of pixels/100)
 *  to keep them in a reasonable range.
 *  Returns a negative size if it is popped.*/
public int size(){
    int s = (int) ((this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI)/100);
    if (popped) { s = 0 - s; }
    return s;
}



}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: so just all of my code? there's not THAT much i just thought it would be wise to post the section with the problem

Comment: BTW - 'Short' can be 150 lines of code if the problem *really* needs it.

Comment: You certainly are using 'this' a lot. Are you sure you've structured the program in a logical way?

Comment: My lecturer has insisted we always use this for local fields and variables, not sure why.

Comment: I'm not sure if having a for-loop that goes the opposite way of the outer for-loop is a good idea. Why not have two separate for-loops?

Comment: just curiosity, what methods pop() and expand()
 do?

Comment: the nested for loop doesn't go the opposite direction, it just starts one position ahead and stops before the end. It needed to be nested so it could iterate through the list and check if any of the balloon objects are touching any others.

Comment: the pop method makes a balloon change color, sets it's state to popped so it cant be expanded anymore. Expand increases the radius of the clicked balloon by a random number between 4 and 10

Comment: *"added more code"*  I recommend 1 SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

is this right?

```
 for (int j = 1; j <this.balloons.length; j++) {
```

doesn't it allow i and j to be equal, so you end up asking whether a balloon is touching itself? Do you mean j = i + 1 ?

If you are now getting null pointer exceptions, get into a debugger and step through until you see where. My guess is that you are visiting array items that have been popped, and hence are null.

```
  if (this.balloons[i].isTouching(this.balloons[j]) && this.balloons[j] != null)
```

You are testing this.balloons[j] for null after you are using it. I'd put some null checks before trying to work with each item.

Comment: that is what i meant to achieve, i just adjusted that but i keep getting null pointer exceptions at:
`if (this.balloons[i].isTouching(this.balloons[j]) && this.balloons[j] != null)` which has been edited to just `if (this.balloons[i].isTouching(this.balloons[j]))`

Comment: `public boolean isTouching(Balloon other){
    if (this.popped || other.popped) return false;
    double dx = other.centerX - this.centerX;
    double dy = other.centerY - this.centerY;
    double dist = other.radius + this.radius;
    return (Math.hypot(dx,dy) < dist);`

if either are popped in returns false so I can't see what the problem is

Comment: If you set balloons[x] to null then you can't call balloons[x].popped you have this.balloons[i] = null; and this.balloons[j] = null;

Comment: hi buddy is possible to add a word inside the balloon